# Media Source Extensions appendBuffer recovery

Tags: media-source

How can I recover from appendBuffer errors resulting from the following scenarios?

- missing data
- data out of order

Comment: Audio or video? Which MIME/container would be used?

Comment: Audio and video. I'm open to anything. I'm currently using video/webm; codecs="opus, vp9"

Comment: How would "missing data" occur?  What would be appended in its place?

Comment: @AnthumChris For example, if the connection drops. Nothing would be appended in its place. New data would continue to be appended when the connection is reestablished.

Answer (score 1):

Only guesses here...I would assume that out-of-order recoverability depends on format of the media container being decoded (WebM, Ogg, etc).  Browsers' [`decodeAudioData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) function worked fine when receiving Ogg Opus files with explicitly out-of-order/missing pages (created with [opus-file-splitter](https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-stream-audio/tree/master/utils/opus-file-splitter)).  I would assume that browsers use the same underlying stream decoding implementation for both `decodeAudioData` and MSE buffers, therefore MSE should handle missing pages/segments without issue.

Unfortunately, MSE does not support `audio/ogg codecs="opus"` so my test files can't be immediately used for testing.  I'm not yet familiar with WebM container, but I eventually be doing tests with re-ordering `audio/webm codecs="opus"` files into MSE for another project and can let you know the results when that happens!

Answer (score 0):

- Missing data would just create a gap in the buffer that would need some gap skipping logic during playback, i.e. when stuck at the end of a range set the `currentTime` to the beginning of the next range and continue playback
- Adding segments out of order should not be a problem as long as [`SourceBuffer.mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/mode) is set to `segments` which will make sure that the timestamps of the segments are preserved

Comment: If I discard a few seconds of data and then attempt to continue with appendBuffer, I see MediaError {code: 3, message: "CHUNK_DEMUXER_ERROR_APPEND_FAILED: Got a block with a timecode before the previous block."} I can confirm that my SourceBuffer has mode = segments.